# C++ : interpreting hex in a char* as uint8_t

Tags: c++, char, hex

I need to have a char* in the below format having some hex values.

```
char *buf = new char(12);
buf[0] = 0x2;
buf[1] = 0x0;
buf[2] = 0x3;
buf[3] = 0x3;
buf[4] = 0x0;
buf[5] = 0x0;
buf[6] = 0x6;
buf[7] = 0x4;
buf[8] = 0x0;
buf[9] = 0x2;
buf[10] =0x0;
buf[11] =0x0;
```

When i try to print them this way -

```
std::string hex_string;
create_hex_str((uint8_t*)buf, 12, hex_string);
std::cout << hex_string;
```

Definition of the print function :

```
void create_hex_str(uint8_t *data, int len, std::string &tgt)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::hex << std::setfill('0');
    ss << "\n";
    for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        ss << std::setw(2) << static_cast<unsigned>(data[i]) << " ";        
    }
    target = ss.str();
}
```

I get totally different output :
    f0 a1 56 08 28 02 3c f6 40 f8 56 08

Can somebody please help me out? I am sorry if this is a really trivial question but I can simply not understand what is going on here. What am I doing wrong? And I HAVE to represent the byte array as a char*.

Comment: Please, paste a working snippet next time... target will not compile as it is, includes are missing, etc.

Comment: Why use `new` here instead of direct declaration?

Comment: Why don't you return `std::string` instead of having the reference argument?

Comment: @UchiaItachi I have used it currently because in the future I will have to allocate memory dynamically and add hex based on input flags.

Comment: @nneonneo - I could do that as well. This is just an existing function that i was re-using.

Comment: The question doesn't mention a design requirement that this code should only run on a system with an unsigned integer type that is **exactly** 8 bits wide. In fact, the use of `uint8_t` here seems entirely gratuitous; `unsigned char` would be a much better choice.

Answer (score 5):

```
new char(12);
```

That allocates memory for a single character and initialises it with the value 12. Use `[]` to allocate an array:

```
new char[12];
```

But only use `new[]` if you actually need dynamic allocation; if you only need the array within a block of code, then use an automatic one:

```
char buf[12];
```

If you really do need `new[]`, then remember to delete it (with `delete[]`, not just `delete`) when you've finished it. Better still, use a [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) type such as `std::string` or `std::vector<char>` to manage the array for you.

Comment: @LaszloPapp: Indeed, as I said in the second paragraph.

Comment: OK, that was not there yet when I checked. :)

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I have a char* because in the future I will need to dynamically create hex based on input flags and put into it. I just tried with a char array it prints the right hex. It does not with a char * though.

Comment: @Roshan: Did you make the change to use `[]` rather than `()`? As I said, `new char(12)` doesn't allocate enough memory, so you're likely to get data corruption or other undefined behaviour. (And if you do need a dynamic array, I strongly advise you to use `std::string` or `std::vector<char>` rather than messing around with `new`).

Comment: I did try that as well @MikeSeymour But I dont get what is expected. It wokred with an array though. I dont understand why..

Comment: I need to use this because I need a char* to pass into another structure. Okay i will consider std::vector<char> thank you. I am wondering why this unexplained behavior though

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: [Click here](http://ideone.com/eEf99Y) for the online compilation and execution.

Here is a working code. You should use new char[12] rather than new char(12), but in this special case, you do not even need the new. The former will construct an array with 12 elements, but the later just calls the constructor for one element.

Also, note that you used "target" instead of 'tgt', so you have not actually set the output argument.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

void create_hex_str(uint8_t *data, int len, std::string &tgt)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::hex << std::setfill('0');
    ss << "\n";
    for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        ss << std::setw(2) << static_cast<unsigned>(data[i]) << " ";        
    }
    tgt = ss.str();
}

int main()
{
    /* char buf[] = {
        0x2,
        0x0,
        0x3,
        0x3,
        0x0,
        0x0,
        0x6,
        0x4,
        0x0,
        0x2,
        0x0,
        0x0
    }; */

    char *buf = new char[12];
    buf[0] = 0x2;
    buf[1] = 0x0;
    buf[2] = 0x3;
    buf[3] = 0x3;
    buf[4] = 0x0;
    buf[5] = 0x0;
    buf[6] = 0x6;
    buf[7] = 0x4;
    buf[8] = 0x0;
    buf[9] = 0x2;
    buf[10] =0x0;
    buf[11] =0x0;

    std::string hex_string;
    create_hex_str((uint8_t*)buf, 12, hex_string);
    std::cout << hex_string;
}
```

I built this code with the following command: `g++ --std=c++11 main.cpp && ./a.out`

Output is: `02 00 03 03 00 00 06 04 00 02 00 00`

Comment: Thank you. But I need it to work with a char*, because in the future I will be adding dynamic hex bytes. I tried this too, it works with a char[] but not with a char*. Any ideas why?

Comment: @Roshan: I already gave the explanation for that case too, but I have just updated the code for your convenience. Can you try this, please to run it through the provided comment and compare with my (i.e. expected) output?

Comment: Yeah i tried this. Still not working fine for me :(
c0 a1 56 08 28 d2 45 f6 c0 f1 56 08

Comment: I dont know the exact explanation, but it was being interpreted wrongly. I used reinterpret_cast and it works fine now. :-) Thank you for the help.

Comment: @Roshan: reinterpret cast where? Also, please select the solution once it works.

Comment: Could you make an live example on any of the online compilers? Would get upvoted more easily by lazy readers like me who don't like copying code.

Comment: @TemplateRex: how to do that? I can compile and execute the code in here for instance, but what to do then? http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp11_online.php

Comment: @TemplateRex: I added a "TL;DR: ..." at the beginning. Is it okay this way? This another online compiler seems to provide explicit url.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com Copy the code, make sure it compiles, then use the "Share" button to get a permalink to post at the bottom of your answer

Comment: Ideone is fine too, +1

Comment: @TemplateRex: do you know why I stopped receiving the 10 points? I did not get that for your upvote, nor the two upvotes in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547537/c11-multiple-definitions-not-odr-used/18547665#18547665 Should I report it on meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Google for rep cap ;-)

Comment: Hmm, but that is unfair for the work put into this, no? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32160/what-is-the-daily-reputation-cap-and-how-can-i-hit-it I see there is a daily limit. :( Will I get the reputation for upvotes tomorrow, or they are lost?

Comment: @TemplateRex: ^^^^^ Also, do you know an online compiler with the Qt libraries available?