# c++11 multiple definitions not odr-used?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

Consider the following C++11 program:

translation unit #1:

```
int x = 3;

int main() {}
```

translation unit #2:

```
int x = 4;
```

Is this program ill-formed?  Why / why not?

gcc complains that:

```
error: multiple definition of `x'
```

The only relevant rule I can see is in 3.2.4:

> Every program shall contain exactly one definition of every non-inline function or variable that is odr-used in that program

But `x` isn't odr-used in the program. (or is it?)

Is this a gcc bug?  Or am I missing something in the standard?

Comment: Does your translation unit #2 contain *only* that one line?

Comment: @KerrekSB: Correct, both TUs are completely listed.

Comment: user1131467: it is a somewhat similar discussion from today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544249/what-is-the-difference-between-the-global-variables-in-c-and-c/18544320#18544320

Comment: @AndrewTomazos: any reason why you have not selected an answer yet? What more can we do for you?

Answer (score 1):

It is not a gcc bug, but standard behavior.

Practically speaking, `int x;` defines a symbol which leads to a linker error if defined twice or more.

#### [C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf) 3.5 (9)

> Two names that are the same (Clause 3) and that are declared in different scopes shall denote the same variable, function, type, enumerator, template or namespace if

— both names have external linkage or else both names have internal linkage and are declared in the same translation unit; and

— both names refer to members of the same namespace or to members, not by inheritance, of the same class; and

— when both names denote functions, the parameter-type-lists of the functions (8.3.5) are identical; and

— when both names denote function templates, the signatures (14.5.6.1) are the same.

Comment: Sorry this answer is wrong.  [basic.link] just tells us when two declarations refer to the same entity.  It says nothing about how many of the declarations can be definitions.  The number of allowed definitions is specified in [basic.odr], but for the OP case this isn't specified.  This is a standard defect.  There is a sentance in [basic.odr] that starts like "multiple definitions are allowed if".  This should be changed to "muliple definitions are not allowed unless".  This would fix the standard defect.  I haven't had time to follow up on this defect.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos: feel free to open a discussion about this on std-proposals@isocpp.org

Comment: Already did a while back.  We came to the mentioned conclusion.  Don't know if a formal DR has been filed.  It's not really important.  Implementations already implement it in the "fixed" fashion, so likely noone cares.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos: do you have a link at hand? Shall I update my answer accordingly?

Comment: @AndrewTomazos: what is missing from the answers, still?

Answer (score 1):

I know you're looking for an explanation based on the standards, but in this case I don't think that is necessary.

Global variable and function declarations, unless declared `static`, have external linkage.

A declaration with an initialization counts as a definition. You're declaring the same variable `x` in two places and initializing it with 2 different values. (In fact, it could even be the same value.)

Meaning, you have 2 definitions of the same variable. That's for sure.

Meaning, your example above violates the ODR.

I remember this being the case even from pre-historical times in C.

In C++ instead of using `static` we can place all global definitions inside the `anonymous namespace`, the effect is the same.

Comment: It's by definition. Like I said, in your example "int x" is multiply defined. I don't know the relevant sections in the standard, but I remember this being so since I first learned C and C++.

Comment: A declaration with an initialization counts as a definition. You're declaring the same variable (x) in two places and initializing it with 2 different values. Meaning, two definitions of the same variable.

Comment: See also the link I posted below the question for a similar answer with the relevant Standard quote